# leaflet.js remove hover effect

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have add hover effect(mouseover, mouseout) in marker.
my code is below

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {  });
marker.on('mouseover', function(e) { marker.openPopup(); });
marker.on('mouseout', function(e) { marker.closePopup(); });
```

I have added too much marker on my map, added hover effect in all marker. 
But i want to some changes like if click on marker remove mouseout effect from current marker and if click on close button in open pop up so add mouseout effect in marker.

so how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an eventhandler you can use the `off` method. There is also a `once` method which will add a eventhandler which will only fire once and then unbinds itself:

```
function clickHandler (mouseEvent) {
    console.log(mouseEvent);
}

// Add event
L.marker([0,0]).on('click', clickHandler);

// Remove event
L.marker([0,0]).off('click', clickHandler);

// Add event which will fire once
L.marker([0,0]).once('click', clickHandler);
```

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events